# Pipeline stage ID doesn't follow the stage when reordered

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using the Jenkins pipeline stage view plugin REST API. When I use the path `/job/:job-name/wfapi/runs` I get a list of the last jobs.

Yesterday I renamed all the stages and also changed the order of the stages a bit. Here is a part of the JSON file, **#152** is before the change and **#153** is after:

```
"name": "#153",
  "id": "6",
  "name": "Compile",
  "id": "13",
  "name": "Flash image",
  "id": "19",
  "name": "Generate log",
...
"name": "#152",
  "id": "6",
  "name": "1. Compile",
  "id": "13",
  "name": "2. Flash image",
  "id": "19",
  "name": "3. Prepare hardware",
  ...
  "id": "31",
  "name": "6. Generate log",
```

What I feel is very strange is that the **"Generate log"** stage in **#153** has taken over the stage id 19 from **"3. Prepare hardware"** in #152 (**"Generate log"** failed so I don't have any id number for **"Prepare hardware"** that comes later in the pipeline). I thought that the id was unique for a stage setup and that the id would change if you change the stage settings more than just renaming it.

My goal is to gather statistics over failed stages. But if the id isn't following the stages when I reorder them I don't know how to distinguish one test from another. Well, as long as I don't rename the stages I can use the name as my unique identifier, but that seems not so smart.

Does anyone have some solution for this or information about how the stage id tag works?

Version of my pipeline plugins (not the latest):

```
Pipeline: Declarative v1.1.9
Pipeline: Declarative Extension Points API v1.1.9   
Pipeline: Groovy v2.39  
Pipeline: Job v2.12.2   
Pipeline: Multibranch v2.16 
Pipeline: Nodes and Processes v2.13 
Pipeline: Supporting APIs v2.14
```